# Simple sending data between client/server

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, client, multiplayer

I am trying to send data on a simple multiplayer game, using Var1 and Var2 in this example. Var1 should sent and be stored as Var2 in the other user's instance.

The code I have sort of works, except I think the server is sending data to itself and overriding the data it receives, because if I load the client and initialize/send data, the server sees it. Then if I go to the server and initialize/send data, the client sees it. But if I go back to the client and send data, the server no longer sees it. It's like the server is acting as both a client and a server. Am I doing something wrong somewhere?

```
public class mouseController : NetworkBehaviour
{
    GameLoop g;
void Start()
{
    GameObject thePlayer = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
    g = thePlayer.GetComponent<GameLoop>(); 
}
void Update()
{

    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (isServer)
    {
        if (g.var1 > 0)
        {
            Rpcsenddata(g.var1);
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        if (g.var1 > 0)
        {
            Cmdsenddata(g.var1);
        }
    }
 }
    [Command]
    void Cmdsenddata(int i)
    {
        g.var2 = i;
    }
    [ClientRpc]
    public void Rpcsenddata(int i)
    {
        g.var2 = i;
    }
}
```

https://gyazo.com/b77e2ce35ec5f4d47147894c9430da03

(the data being sent is the card selected by your opponent. The server is the window on the right)

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed it by adding a !isLocalPlayer check

```
[ClientRpc]
public void Rpcsenddata(int i)
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer) {  
        g.ehandSelected = i;
    }
}
```